# How to iterate over Vector of Vectors

Tags: java, vector

How do I iterate over a Vector of Vectors in Java?
I tried doing it like in C++ :

```
Vector<Vector<String>> elements = new Vector<Vector<String>>();
// ...
System.out.print(elements[0][0]);
```

But obviously that would not work.

Comment: How would you iterate over one vector? Then do the same thing for one vector that contains one vector.

Comment: The code you have here would be `elements.get(0).get(0)` in Java. It's not iterating anything, however.

Comment: Yea, I know its not iterating, I was just giving an example for accessing an element :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To iterate through all the elements use a code similar to the following:

```
for (Vector<String> v : elements) {
    for (String s : v) {
        // Use s as you like
    }
}
```

To access a specific element:

```
int x = ...
int y = ...
...
String s = elements.get(x).get(y);
```

Comment: If you find useful this answer you can upvote it and flag it as the right answer with the green check