# Equivalent of for x, y in z in java

Tags: java, python, loops, for-loop

In python, you can use the structure `for x in [a, b, c, d]` for loops. This can be replicated using a foreach loop in java.

What about if I wanted to replicate a `for x, y in z` loop, such as the one below, in java?

```
for x_off, y_off in ( (1, 2), (-1, 2), (1, -2), (-1, -2), (2, 1), (-2, 1), (2, -1), (-2, -1) ):
    #do something
```

Comment: Java doesn't really do tuples like that, but use a tuple. And then `for-each` tuple.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35114972/how-to-iterate-over-vector-of-vectors

Comment: As prior comments say -- destructuring (or the more limited tuple unpacking Python implements) is a feature not all languages have. (If you want a JVM-based language that has it, consider Clojure, not Java).

Answer (score 1):

I ended up just using variables for each index. But this won't be useful for 2d arrays with large counts for each inner array.

```
int[][] offsets = new int[][] { {0, 1}, {0, -1}, {1, 0}, {-1, 0}, {1, 1}, {1, -1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, -1} };

for(int[] offset: offsets) {
    int x = offset[0], y = offset[1];
    // do something with x and y
```

Answer (score 1):

You should create a class for storing the three values:

```
final class Point3D {
    private final int x, y, z;
    // constructor, getters, and equals/hashCode/toString here
}
```

Then you can use an array initializer with an enhanced for loop:

```
for (Point3D point : new Point3D[] { new Point3D(1, 1, 1), new Point3D(-1, 1, 1),
                                     new Point3D(-1, -1, 1), new Point3D(1, -1, 1) }) {
    // code here
}
```

It reads better if you create the array separately, especially if there are many points:

```
Point3D[] points = {
        new Point3D( 1,  1,  1), new Point3D(-1,  1,  1),
        new Point3D(-1, -1,  1), new Point3D( 1, -1,  1),
        new Point3D( 1,  1, -1), new Point3D(-1,  1, -1),
        new Point3D(-1, -1, -1), new Point3D( 1, -1, -1)
};
for (Point3D point : points) {
    // code here
}
```